# Return count of specific/unique number from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking to create a function that will return a count of the number of occurences of a specified number in a file.

```
def countingNumber(num):

        infile = open('text.txt', 'r')
        contents = infile.read()

        count = 0


        for line in contents.split('\n'):
            if str(number) in line:
                count +=1


        return count
```

Everything works, but I am getting more than the desired number, so say for example that I want to search for the number 30 and type:

```
countingNumber(30)

I will also get a count of any lines that have the number 300 or 3000 in it. Is there a way to get unique numbers counts?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex boundaries `\b`.

**Ex:**

```
def countingNumber(num):
    count = 0
    with open('text.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(num), line):
                count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: `re.findall` could be more direct. Either way, regex rocks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the line into words (using split()), and then check if str(number) exists in the resulting array.